# How to configure karma and jasmine for Office Addin

Tags: typescript, karma-jasmine, office-addins, excel-addins

I am trying to configure karma and jasmine for Office Excel AddIn.

I have configuration like below:

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Fri Nov 26 2021 11:34:29 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords:karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine', "karma-typescript"],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js',
      'src/**/**.spec.ts'
    ],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-typescript'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false,
      jasmine: {
        random: false,
        seed: '0',
        stopOnFailue: false
      } // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    // list of files / patterns to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords:karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
      // source files, that you wanna generate coverage for
      // do not include tests or libraries
      // (these files will be instrumented by Istanbul)
      'src/**/*.ts': ["karma-typescript", 'coverage']
    },

    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords:karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml', 'coverage', "karma-typescript"],
    // optionally, configure the reporter
    coverageReporter: {
      type : 'html',
      dir : 'coverage/'
    },

    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,

    mime: {
      'text/x-typescript': ['ts', 'tsx']
    },
    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,

    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
      thresholds: {
        statements: 80,
        lines: 80,
        branches: 80,
        functions: 80
      }
    },

    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords:karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser instances should be started simultaneously
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

But it hit issue `Some of your tests did a full page reload!`, and the result in webbrowser will be refreshed.